# mapkit framework is not present in xcode

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, frameworks, mapkit

I am working on a project where I am using mapView, in projects build phases mapkit framework is not present what could be the problem, please check the image below 
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take the mapkit framework from another xcode or download it from the frameworks section in the apple developers website. You simply have to copy it and add it to xcode or you can even add it to your project from the folder which contains all the frameworks. If they still don't come then you will have to reinstall your xcode. Hope it works out just fine.

Or you can directly download from here [MapKit.framework](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/74641080/MapKit.framework.zip)

Comment: I searched apple developer website but could not find the location from where I can download mapkit framework, please suggest.

Comment: Do you have any other xcode with you or someone you can get from ?

Comment: yes, I have another mac with xcode installed, but I don't know how to export framework from there.

Comment: In most modern versions of XCode, the MapKit framework is already there so you _don't need to download it_ as is implied here; instead, you just have to find it, and add it to your project.  To do this, click on your project in the Project Navigator (or press command-1).  Under TARGETS, select your application, and ensure the 'General' page is showing up.  Scroll down on the 'General' page, and at the bottom you should see "Linked Frameworks and Libraries".  Click the + sign, locate the MapKit.framework, select, and click 'Add'.

Comment: @Jeffro Haha .... This one's good ... The mapkit framework has been added to all versions of xcode since 3.0 and sometimes the framework is accidentally deleted or and then we need to download it... please read the question clearly ....

Comment: @IronManGill Oh, oops yes you are right, I see your point.  I found this question by searching for the error message I was getting, "mapkit framework is not present in xcode."  For me, I just forgot to add it, problem solved.  It wasn't missing from my XCode installation.  I suspect I'm not the only one who lands on this question in the same situation, and simply needs to add the framework to the project.

Answer (score 1):

Check if you can retrieve frameworks from the original folder :

Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator6.1.sdk/System/Library

Answer (score 0):

In any previous application making you had delete the framework directly that's why it was not showing in xcode. please reinstall the xcode you will get it. or you can download it from apple site.

Comment: I was using mapquests map frame work i.e. mqmapkit.framework, now I have removed that.

Comment: check this link..hope this will work for you... http://developer.mapquest.com/web/products/featured/apple-ios-maps-api